# On examples/sumo/grid.py simulation, there are several detectors, how to get the data

Tags: sumo, flow-project

On the example program(`examples/sumo/grid.py`), when on simulation, we can observe there are four detectors around an intersection, so how do we get the data from these detectors?

On the code file, there are any codes about these detectors.

Comment: I know this is about 'output', and after (examples/sumo/grid.py) simulation, we can see there are some outputs: Round 0, return: 56.61810241121026
Average, std return: 56.61810241121026, 0.0
Average, std speed: 10.31087686612867, 0.0
How do these outputs be created?

Answer (score 1):

About how to add detectors, I find the solution:

On the code:

```
tl_logic.add("center0", phases=phases, programID=1,detectorGap=1,showDetectors=True,tls_type="actuated")
    tl_logic.add("center1", phases=phases, programID=1,detectorGap=1,showDetectors=True,tls_type="actuated")
    tl_logic.add("center2", phases=phases, programID=1,detectorGap=1,showDetectors=True,tls_type="actuated")
    tl_logic.add("center3", phases=phases, programID=1,detectorGap=1,showDetectors=True,tls_type="actuated")
    tl_logic.add("center4", phases=phases, programID=1,detectorGap=1,showDetectors=True,tls_type="actuated")
    tl_logic.add("center5", phases=phases, programID=1,detectorGap=1,showDetectors=True,tls_type="actuated")
```

There is a small question is about `detectorGap`, on `params.py/TrafficLightParams`, the description about detectorGap is that:

```
detectorGap : int, optional
            used for actuated traffic lights
            determines the time distance between the (automatically generated)
            detector and the stop line in seconds (at each lanes maximum
            speed), **used for actuated traffic lights**
```

So, I set detectorGap =1 , and the maximum speed =35km/h, the distance of the detector is: maximum speed(km/h?) * detectorGap(s).
My understanding is right? @nathanlct

The result is that: [image]

Answer (score 0):

For the detectors, look at the docstring of the `add` function in `flow/core/params.py` in the class `TrafficLightParams`:

```
file : str, optional
    which file the detector shall write results into
```

---

For the average return and speed, have a look in `flow/core/experiment.py`, line 145.

Comment: And, another question is : how to add detectors on the environment?

Comment: Not sure, but there is a `show_detectors` param in `TrafficLightParams`. Otherwise I guess they are systematically added to all traffic lights? I don't think you can do it without traffic lights.

Comment: So, about the detector's type, on grid.py example, the detector's type is e1, right? If i want to change to e2, how to do ?

Comment: And, when I test 5x5 intersections and each intersection has four detectors, there are some warnings on the SUMO: Warning: Unused states in tlLogic 'center6', program '1' in phase 0 after tl-index 3
Warning: At actuated tlLogic 'center6', actuated phase 1 has no controlling detector
Warning: At actuated tlLogic 'center6', actuated phase 3 has no controlling detector
Warning: Unused states in tlLogic 'center4', program '1' in phase 0 after tl-index 3  , I am not sure if these warnings can influence my test results. I want to collect how many vehicles are runing/staying on one intersection.